# How to add User Meta as a placeholder in WooCommerce New Order email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking for a php snippet that I can add in order to add a placeholder to WooCommerce "New Order" emails. I want to add custom user meta as the placeholder.

As far as I can tell, I'd need to add this to functions.php.

```
function wpa_filter_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
    // Get WC_Order object from email
    $order = $email->object;
    $wpcf_sales_rep = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wpcf_sales_rep', true);
    
    // Add new placeholders
    $new_placeholders = array(
        '{_sales_rep}'       => $order->get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wpcf_sales_rep', true),
    );
    // return the string with new placeholder replacements
    return str_replace( array_keys( $new_placeholders ), array_values( $new_placeholders ), $string );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'wpa_filter_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
```

Not sure if I need the 4th line - so any help or guidance on correcting this code would be perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know about this line.

```php
    $wpcf_sales_rep = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wpcf_sales_rep', true);
```

It doesn't do anything useful: it stores your usermeta data into a variable called `$wpcf_sales_rep`, but then the rest of your code doesn't use the variable anywhere.